# How to control DB schema (varchar length) of generated NServiceBus data tables

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

By default *NServiceBus* generates DB-schema based on code (with NHibernate's `ConventionModelMapper`, I think). Thus string-properties are mapped to `NVARCHAR(255)` columns. Any chance to change/modify `NVARCHAR` length?

I tried a manual DB schema change after creation, but that feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define a single custom mapping (without need to create a custom mapping for all sagas). See https://docs.particular.net/samples/nhibernate/custom-mappings